# Run a JQuery script only on childs of one element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, children

Is there an easy way of running a JQuery script just on one specific form and it's children without effecting other forms on the website.

At the moment I use the child selector together with any other selector, but is there a command that the following selectors just match within the children of my form?

Thanks

Comment: Normally, that would be `$('#yourform')`, with `<form id="yourform"`. Note, `id` attributes are meant to be *unique* on the DOM, so you can point to just one element; don't reuse `id`s, use a `class` to indicate series relationship to other elements. `#` in a selector and CSS is an `id` selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

```
$('#myform').find('.otherclass').css({color: 'red'})
```

The selector `.otherclass` is searched only inside `#myform`.

And with a small refactoring:

```
var $f = function(selector) { return $('#myform').find(selector); }
```

You can use:

```
$f('.otherclass').css({color: 'red'})
```

To get an scoped version of your jQuery function.

Comment: Thanks! I am new to jQuery so I didn't know how to use variables for selectors.

Answer (score 0):

Or you ca directly use

```
$('#myform .otherclass').css({color: 'red'})
```

You can add event handler also using above syntex.
Ex.

```
$('#myform .otherclass').click(function(){
// Some code
}) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Methods to Navigate Down the DOM Hierarchy     Method Description

children()  - Selects the children of all of the elements in the jQuery object

children(selector) - Selects all of the elements that match the selector and that are children of the elements in the jQuery object

contents() - Returns the children and text content of all the elements in the jQuery object

find() - Selects the descendants of the elements in the jQuery object

find(selector),find(HTMLElement),find(HTMLElement[]) - Selects the elements that match the selector and that are descendants of the
elements in the jQuery object find(jQuery)

or

The Relationship Selectors  Selector Description

selector selector  - Selects elements that match the second selector and that are descendants of the elements matched by the first selector

selector > selector - Selects elements that match the second selector and that are children of the elements matched by the first selector

selector + selector - Selects elements that match the second selector and are the next sibling to an element that matches the first selector

selector ~ selector - Selects elements that match the second selector and that are siblings to (and that appear after) an element that matches the first selector